# Application.Run returning Error 438, not calling macro

Tags: excel, vba

In one workbook I have

```
Sub test1()
Dim wb1 As Workbook

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("X:\****\****\****\Book2.xlsm")
Application.Run  "'X:\****\****\****\Book2.xlsm'!test2" 'ERROR HERE

End Sub
```

In another workbook I have

```
Sub test2()

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1") = "Hi"

End Sub
```

But it keep error with "Object Doesn't Support This Property Or Method"

I've tried

```
Application.Run  "'Book2.xlsm'!test2"
Application.Run  "Book2.xlsm!test2"
Application.Run  ("'X:\****\****\****\Book2.xlsm'!test2")
```

And many similar syntax's and all have the same error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The other workbook must be open I believe.

Comment: I do open the workbook first right before that line

Comment: Is `test2` in a regular code module?  Any chance you've defined another variable called `Application` somewhere in the global scope?

Comment: No I haven't defined that and it is in a regular module, not in a sheet module. The code posted below worked for me so I have no idea what's going on. Any specific references need to be checked or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You need to build up the string properly using the name of the file.

```
Sub test1()

Dim wb1 As Workbook

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("X:\ ...\Book2.xlsm")
Application.Run "'" & wb1.Name & "'!test2"

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great! Works perfectly, thank you so much! Do you know why I have to do it this way?

Comment: Not sure. This code is equivalent to your first two attempts above so is a bit odd. If you step through check the value of `wb1.name`.

Comment: In fact your example works for me so something else is going on, perhaps as per Tim Williams's comment.

Comment: That is very odd. I wrote it in a brand new worksheet, all code in the VBA project is what I wrote in my initial post. Only variable declared is the workbook. Very Odd.